# submit form after correct reply from post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

index.php:

```
$.post('example.php',{ id:pin },
function(data) {$("#test").html(data);}
<div id='test'></div>
<form><input...></form>
```

Using the above i'd hoped to drop a script into example.php page that would cause the page to submit...

example.php:

```
 if($_post['id']==5){
 echo '<script>function submitform(){document.getElementById("form").submit();}
 </script>';i}
```

I had planned to add a DOM even listener for mouse movement key press... and then have that fire off the submitform() script... I tried a few things without luck and I know there has to be a cleaner/Working way...

Thanks,
JT

Comment: Don't wrap the code in a function, and make sure the form has the id attribute

Comment: I don't understand, you're using jquery to post the data and using the returned data to then output html which has js in which then does more js? lol

Comment: Im at first making a link emailing it when the user click the email link to activate account then comes back to the page the new script will cause the actually form to submit.

Comment: @koala_dev write that as a answer! worked like a chare

Comment: @tman Glad to hear it worked, I just posted an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not calling your `submitform()` function, but since you want to run the code right away I think it's better if you don't use the function at all and just output the code. Also make sure the form has the id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly you want to submit a form after having submitted data already?
If so why don't you just submit everything and process it server side only if conditions are met?

Comment: This should really be in a comment dude.

Comment: Im at first making a link emailing it when the user click the email link to activate account then comes back to the page the new script will cause the actually form to submit.

Comment: alright but then you're about to submit an empty form from a new page aren't you?